# Twilio "Gather input on call" is having pauses

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am using Twilio Studio and in the flow I am using "Gather input on Call" widget, and "Split based on" after that. It works fine, but on one of the keypress I am setting a variable and again using second level of "Gather input on call" widget and "split based on" combination. The second time it works after having a long pause in the speech.

- Is it possible to use "Gather input on call" widget twice or many
  times in one flow?
- Can anyone suggest something to reduce the pause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using digit input (DTMF), if you know the number of expected digits, set that in the widget (Number of digits) so you don’t have to wait for the digit timeout to proceed to the next digit (which is that gap you here).